# Excel to JSON parsing

Tags: json, excel

I am trying to parse Excel data to JSON to feed drop downs in HTML. I am having a hard time getting this to work. I have looked all over the web. I am new to javascript so i find it overwhelming.

There seems to be a lot of scripting and to make this work. If anyone can help and explain how to set this up i would be greatly appreciative.

Thanks All,
HAppleknocker

Comment: Please, provide more info: Do you have a backend server? What language do you use? Do you have an Excel file in `CSV` format or it is full-featured `Excel` file?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You say you're having a hard time, but with what exactly?

You might have a look at the SheetJS library, https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Comment: Ok let me see if i can explain. I have an Excel file (.xlsx) that changes daily. For example: First Name, Last name, account name, email. I need that data to be converted to JSON to feed dropdown menus on a website. I am not using a server. This is just HTML, CSS & Javascript. I have found scripts online and through SheetJS but cant get them to work. There seem to be several javascript files that need to live on the computer (xlxs.worker.js and others) Even when i have those installed scripts do not work. All i need to do is convert the excel file information and feed it to a dropdown in HTML.

Comment: I did find this link http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/ but how do i get that to work? i copy the source code but no luck

Comment: Help????please!!!

Comment: ok no help here!!

Answer (score 0):

This article explained clearly how to make the JSON object from a Excel File.  After getting the JSON object as a string you can use it to do anything.

In here used sheet js and sample javaScript code available on GitHub.

[How to convert Excel data into JSON object using JavaScript](https://medium.com/@ydulanjanii/how-to-convert-excel-data-into-json-object-using-javascript-1c4e0d3e97ee)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#fileUploader").change(function(evt){
                var selectedFile = evt.target.files[0]; //Get the ExcelFile
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(event) {
                  var data = event.target.result;
                  var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                      type: 'binary'
                  });
                  workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {

                      var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
                      var json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
                      document.getElementById("jsonObject").innerHTML = json_object;

                    })
                };

                reader.onerror = function(event) {
                  console.error("File could not be read! Code " + event.target.error.code);
                };

                reader.readAsBinaryString(selectedFile);
          });
    });
</script>
```